# Como remover o primeiro nó de uma lista?

Tags: c

void Insere (Lista* list){

```
DadoNo dado;
int p = list->size;
No* n = (No*) malloc(sizeof(No));
n->ant = list->head;

scanf("%s", dado.nome);

if (Busca(list, dado.nome) == NULL){

    n->dado = dado;
    n->prox = list->head;
    list->head = n;
    list->size++;
    n->pos = p;
```

Logo, como acessar n->prox ou n->ant, para n = nó pioneiro, em uma possível remoção ?

Meu código de remoção está sendo o seguinte :

```
if (!listVazia(list)){   // Verifico se a linha está vazia

    if (atual != NULL){   // atual é o ponteiro que retorna da busca

        if (atual->pos == 0 ){   // o primeiro nó inserido na lista

           atual = atual->prox;
        }

        else if( atual == list->head){  // este funciona OK

            list->head = atual->ant;
        }

        else {      // este tammbém apresenta problemas p remover um nó do meio

            aux = atual->ant;
            aux1 = atual->prox;

            aux->prox = aux1;

        }

        free(atual);
        list->size--;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A remoção do primeiro nó é feita alterando o ponteiro `head` para `NULL` e desalocando na memória o Nó que lá está. Uma implementação que contempla esse cenário seria:

```
//remover à cabeça
void Remove (Lista* list){ 
     if (list == NULL || list->head == NULL) return; //se vazia nada a fazer senão sair

     No* NoARemover = list->head; //guarda um ponteiro para o nó que vai ser removido
     list->head = list->head->prox; //faz o head passar a ser o seguinte
     free(NoARemover); //desaloca o antigo head de memoria
     list->size--; //reajusta o size para o valor correto
}
```

Apesar de ser subtil responde de facto á pergunta:

> seus parâmetros próximo e anterior são nulos [...]
>
> Logo, como acessar n->prox ou n->ant, para n = nó pioneiro, em uma
>   possível remoção ?

Se `list->head` for `NULL` a lista já está vazia e já não ha nada a fazer numa remoção. Se `list->head` não for `NULL` então é possível aceder a `list->head->prox`, embora esse possa ser `NULL`. E nesse caso é exatamente o que se pretende pois colocamos `NULL` no `head` através desta instrução:

```
list->head = list->head->prox; //faz o head passar a ser o seguinte
```

Passando assim de 1 elemento para nenhum.

**Edit:**

> com o código que você me passou, não consegui remover o primeiro nó

Não o fez corretamente com o código que indiquei, possivelmente porque tem lógica especifica que não tinha até então explicado, ou porque não o utilizou da forma apropriada.

[Tem aqui um exemplo do Remove a funcionar exatamente como eu o escrevi no Ideone](http://ideone.com/qIz5Mu)

Considerando o código que adicionou na edição:

`if (atual->pos == 0 ){` e `else if( atual == list->head){` são na verdade a mesma coisa, assumindo que as suas posições são incrementais a começar do `0` no inicio.

Se é o caso então ser o `0` ou o `head` é a mesma coisa.

Se `atual` corresponde a `list->head` então

```
list->head = atual->ant;
```

Corresponde a:

```
list->head = list->head->ant;
```

Que como é `NULL` e igual ao `prox`, corresponde na verdade ao que eu tinha escrito!

```
list->head = list->head->prox;
```

A lógica para remover um nó do meio numa lista duplamente ligada é normalmente a seguinte:

```
//o seguinte ao Nó a remover define como anterior o anterior do corrente
atual->prox->ant = atual->ant; 
//o anterior ao Nó a remover define como o próximo do próximo do corrente
atual->ant->prox = atual->prox;
//liberta memoria do no corrente, o a remover
free(atual);
```

É importante também mencionar que esta lógica não irá funcionar se o no do meio for na verdade o ultimo pois `atual->prox->ant` crasha o programa se `atual->prox` for `NULL` logo deverá ser feito um teste especifico para esse caso, e o mesmo acontece no código apresentado.

**Edit 2**:

Olhando para o código todo indicado no *ideone*, vejo que há varias pequenas coisas que necessitam de ajustes, que é visível pela quantidade de *warnings* indicada.

No entanto, para o por a funcionar na parte de remover basta alterar a função para não ter o primeiro `if` pois é igual ao segundo assim como tinha indicado, e se lá estiver não faz nada logo não remove, pois a remoção está a ser feita no `if` a seguir que já não irá executar se entrar no primeiro.

Deve então ficar:

```
    if (atual != NULL){
        /*if (atual->pos == 0){

        }
        else */if( atual == list->head){

            list->head = atual->ant;
        }
        else {

            atual->prox->ant = atual->ant;
            atual->ant->prox = atual->prox;
        }

        free(atual);
        list->size--;
    }
```

Ajustes relevantes:

- A função de `Busca` está a fazer comparação `char` a `char`. Simplifique utilizando `strcmp` da biblioteca `<string.h>` . Esta mesma função não está a retornar `NULL` quando não encontra o texto procurado, que é algo necessário para que o resto do código funcione corretamente.

  Esta função poderia ficar simplesmente:

  ```
  No* Busca ( Lista *list, char *nome){
      No* ptr = list->head;

      while (ptr != NULL){
          //agora compara com strcmp da biblioteca de strings
          if (strcmp( nome, ptr->dado.nome) == 0){ //strcmp devolve 0 quando são iguais
              return ptr;
          }

          ptr = ptr->prox;
      }

      return NULL; //agora retorna NULL caso não nenhum
  }
  ```
- No `RemoverDados` os nós auxiliares já não estão a ser utilizados, estes:

  ```
  void RemoverDados ( Lista *list){
      ...
      No* aux = (No*)malloc(sizeof(No));
      No* aux1 = (No*)malloc(sizeof(No));
  ```

  E por isso podem ser removidos, no entanto, estes também não estariam corretos numa função de remover. Criar um ponteiro é diferente de criar um ponteiro e alocar memória para a estrutura correspondente.

  Ou seja isto:

  ```
  No* aux; //cria só o ponteiro
  ```

  É bem diferente disto:

  ```
  No* aux = (No*)malloc(sizeof(No));
  ```

  Que cria o ponteiro e aloca memória para a estrutura correspondente, e que não é o correto para remover e estava anteriormente a criar uma fuga de memoria. Sempre que necessitamos de ponteiros só para navegar numa lista não é suposto usarmos `malloc`, mas sim apenas criar o ponteiro.
- No main para deixar totalmente correto convêm também ter um retorno, algo como

  ```
  int main(){
      ...
      return 0;
  }
  ```

  Ou utilizando o `#define` que já em `stdlib.h`:

  ```
  int main(){
      ...
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
  ```

**Edit 3**:

Tentando não tornar a minha resposta muito extensa (e já está bastante), o maior problema está de facto na inserção pois não constrói corretamente os ponteiros anteriores. Deve ficar da seguinte forma:

```
if (Busca(list, dado.nome) == NULL){
    ...
    n->dado = dado;
    n->prox = list->head;

    //faltava este if para construir o ant caso não seja o primeiro
    if (list->head != NULL){ 
        list->head->ant = n; //construção do anterior aqui
    }

    list->head = n;
    list->size++;

    n->pos = p;
}
```

Resumindo estamos a fazer `2º->ant = 1º`. Sem os anteriores construídos quando o `RemoverDados` tenta aceder aos anteriores não obtêm valores corretos e por isso simplesmente não funcionava.

O `RemoverDados` também não está completo, de acordo com o que já tinha dito anteriormente:

> É importante também mencionar que esta lógica não irá funcionar se o
>   no do meio for na verdade o ultimo

E para ficar completo deve então passar a ser:

```
if (atual != NULL){

    if( atual == list->head){
        list->head = atual->prox;
    }
    else if (atual -> prox == NULL){ //caso que faltava para o ultimo!
        atual->ant->prox = NULL; //o proximo do penultimo passa a apontar para NULL
    }
    else {
        atual->prox->ant = atual->ant;
        atual->ant->prox = atual->prox;
    }

    free(atual);
    list->size--;
}
```

Comment: Entendi a sua lógica, porém o que na verdade estou tento dificuldade para remover é o primeiro nó da lista, ou seja, aquele que esta sendo colocado numa lista anteriormete vazia.

Comment: @PauloBomfim O código que eu indiquei remove esse elemento. Se `list->head` tiver um elemento e `list->head->prox` for `NULL` funciona na perfeição ficando com `list->head` a `NULL` ou seja vazia.

Comment: como explicado antes, com o código que você me passou, não consegui remover o primeiro nó. Entendi que ele serve para remoção de nó cabeça. Fiz um edit e coloquei a função de remoção para ficar mais fácil o entendimento, já que minha remoção se baseia por uma busca .

Comment: @PauloBomfim já editei a resposta para a contemplar a sua edição e comentário.

Comment: Compreendo a sua lógica, porém não consigo encaixa-la no meu código. A idéia de que 'pos=0' e 'list->head' são a mesma coisa, no meu código não está funcionando. (http://ideone.com/AAS2gC) @Isac, deixei meu código mais completo no Ideone, para ver se você consegue enxergar algo. Os campos de remoção para 'pos==0' está vazio, e para algum nó no meio, não está funcionando.

Comment: @PauloBomfim , ok voltei a re-editar de acordo com o que colocou no Ideone.

Comment: re-editei meu código conforme suas explicações( http://ideone.com/ThNrM0 ) . Em relação à `strcmp` para função `Busca`, eu já havia notado essa possível mudança. Quanto à declaração dos ponteiros auxiliares, não tinha notado essa questão. Estarei deixando lá no Ideone, meu código por completo (incluindo funções que estão funcionando perfeitamente). O intuíto de deixar por completo, o que o torna um pouco mais extenso , é para ver se você consegue identificar o porque da remoção do primeiro ou de um determinado `No` mediano, não está executando como deveria.

Comment: @PauloBomfim Voltei a editar para corrigir as partes especificas à remoção e outras que afetavam a remoção. Aconselho também a rever aqueles pormenores que indiquei como por exemplo `No* ptr = (No*)malloc(sizeof(No));` na função `OrdenaNome`, que continuam no código e não estão corretos.

Comment: modificações feitas a partir da sua nova edição e código funcionando de forma prevista. O problema todo realmente estava na função `Insere`pois não conseguia ajustar o parâmetro `n->prox` para o n inicial, como dito em  _"Logo, como acessar n->prox ou n->ant, para n = nó pioneiro, em uma possível remoção ?"_

Comment: @PauloBomfim Não consegui entender o que disse. `n->prox` ou `n->ant` para o nó inicial devem ficar a `NULL`. Na remoção de um nó "pioneiro" o código relevante executado é `list->head = atual->prox;` que será na verdade `list->head = NULL;` visto que `atual` é o único nó e por isso `atual->prox` tem `NULL`. Mas o código  tinha múltiplas coisas que não o permitia funcionar corretamente, não era só uma.

Comment: Em relação à função `OrdenaNome` estou revisando o código por um todo, e analisando estes e outros detalhes. Em relação ao seu desentendimento com o meu comentário, eu não me expressei direito : a questão de que eu estava falando, era em relação a definição do nó pioneiro em que `-prox`não se relacionava com o futuro nó a ser inserido (no caso, o segundo `no` da lista). Esta situação, posteriormente resolvida por você quando disse _"o maior problema está de facto na inserção pois não constrói corretamente os ponteiros anteriores .. "_. E **sim, múltiplas coisas não permitiam o funcionamento**